# Atomエディタのファイルプレビュー機能をオフにしたい

Tags: atom-editor

[Atom](https://atom.io/)で、ツリービューにあるファイルをシングルクリックするとプレビューとしてタブが開きますが、これを**ダブルクリックでのみ開く**ようにしたいのですが、設定方法やプラグインはありますでしょうか。
（いわゆる[Smart Tabs](https://github.com/atom/tree-view/issues/3)ではありません）

大きなファイルやMinifyされたファイルを何気なくクリックするたびにフリーズするので・・・

Answer (score 4, accepted):

即席で`chary-tree-view`というパッケージを書きました。
インストールするだけでダブルクリックのみで開くようになると思います。
（素の`tree-view`でしかチェックしてないので、もしかすると他のパッケージと競合するかもしれません）

`$ apm install chary-tree-view`

https://atom.io/packages/chary-tree-view

Comment: 天才ですか！すごいですね。さっそく使用してみました。ただ、とても恐縮なのですがバグっぽい動きでした。シングルクリックでは開かなくなりましたが、ダブルクリックで開くと、そのファイルのタブが複数開いてしまいました。

Comment: ごめんなさい、ちょっと寝ぼけていました。修正しましたので`0.2.1`にバージョンアップしてAtomを再起動してください。

Comment: 今度は問題なくいけました。理想の動きで満足です！

Answer (score 1):

参考程度ですが[GitHub](https://github.com/atom/atom)からプロジェクトをダウンロードして、
少し手を加えればそれっぽい動きにできそうです。

**手順**
1.プロジェクトをダウンロードする
2.プロジェクトに移動してモジュールをインストール（`cd atom && npm install`）
3.とりあえず試しにビルドしてみる（`script/build`）
　成功するとアプリケーション配下にAtom.appができます
　※初回は時間がかかります
4.**/node_modules/tree-view/lib/tree-view.coffee**を編集する
　L.85あたり（`handleEvents`）

```
@on 'click', '.entry', (e) =>
  # This prevents accidental collapsing when a .entries element is the event target
  return if e.target.classList.contains('entries')

  @entryClicked(e) unless e.shiftKey or e.metaKey or e.ctrlKey

# ダブルクリック用の処理を追加
@on 'dblclick', '.entry', (e) =>
  # This prevents accidental collapsing when a .entries element is the event target
  return if e.target.classList.contains('entries')

  @entryDblClicked(e) unless e.shiftKey or e.metaKey or e.ctrlKey
```

L.200あたり

```
entryClicked: (e) ->
  entry = e.currentTarget
  isRecursive = e.altKey or false
  switch e.originalEvent?.detail ? 1
    when 1
      @selectEntry(entry)
      # 選択したファイルを開く処理をコメントアウト
      # @openSelectedEntry(false) if entry instanceof FileView
      entry.toggleExpansion(isRecursive) if entry instanceof DirectoryView
    when 2
      if entry instanceof FileView
        @unfocus()
      else if DirectoryView
        entry.toggleExpansion(isRecursive)

  false

# ダブルクリック用の処理を追加
entryDblClicked: (e) ->
  entry = e.currentTarget
  @openSelectedEntry(false) if entry instanceof FileView

false
```

5.もう一度ビルドする（`script/build`）
　※アプリケーション配下のAtom.appは上書きされるので消さなくても大丈夫です

**補足事項**
sublime-tabsが入っていると上手くいかないかもしれません。
※ダブルクリック用のfunction名がかぶっていなければ平気かも（sublime-tabsは`entryDblClicked`という名前を使用しています）。
差し支えなければ一度Atomを削除した方がやりやすいと思います（packageとか入れ直しになってしまいますが）。

・削除する場合は下記をご参照ください

```
1.アプリケーションフォルダの Atom を削除
2.rm -rf ~/.atom
3.rm /usr/local/bin/atom
4.rm /usr/local/bin/apm
5.rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.github.atom.plist
6.rm -rf ~/Library/Application Support/com.github.atom.ShipIt
7.rm -rf ~/Library/Application Support/Atom
```

<strike>[sublime-tabs](https://atom.io/packages/sublime-tabs)というのがあるみたいですね。</strike>

> **Features**
>
> Allows you to single click a file in the tree view to open it
>   temporarily like Sublime Editing a temporary tab keeps it open
>   Saving / Double clicking the tab keeps the tab permanent Browsing the tree
>   view on the left using the :right_arrow: key allows you to open files

Comment: シングルクリックでプレビューされるのを無効にしたい、ということなので逆のような気がします。

Comment: @unarist Atomだとファイルを選択しただけでタブが開くのをやめたいというのと勘違いしてました（自分がその挙動が嫌いだったので・・・）。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: @ita_3y 念のためインストールしてみましたが、 unarist さんの指摘のように希望の動作ではありませんでした。

Comment: @kijtra 回答を編集しました。

Comment: @ita_3y 環境を書いておらず申し訳ないのですが、Windows環境なのです。Atomはバージョンアップが頻繁なため、ソースを変更してもすぐに戻ってしまいそうです。「ユーザー用設定ファイル」のようなものがあれば助かるのですが・・・。